# How can I fix this Nested For Loop script (R) to estimate Model Ages

Tags: r, iteration, nested-for-loop

I'm new to R (and coding in general). The data itself is taken from lead isotope analysis and are lead isotopes.

I was hoping to create a nested for loop which compared the output of an equation to a vertex of integers calculated from sample data.

I can see two issues but I don't know how to address them:
(1): '1:length(num_intervals))' references an integer but perhaps should be a series or a list (?)

(2): the output of the loop overwrites the ModelAge function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#Data for Testing. For obvious reasons, I can't include all my data but here are some samples to create a sample file to compile:

47      18.54400       15.590       38.427
48      18.55900       15.580       38.403
49      18.48100       15.600       38.407
50      18.37400       15.614       38.293
51      19.23800       15.673       37.272
52      18.14200       15.649       38.137
53      18.52500       15.590       38.430
54      18.55000       15.597       38.468
55      18.59200       15.662       37.972
56      18.59500       15.662       37.972
57      18.50000       15.594       38.402

#Model Age Estimations
rm(list = ls())
#library(dplyr)

#assumptions

#growth constant assumptions
decay_constant_u238 <- 1.55125E-10
decay_constant_u235 <- 9.8485E-10
decay_constant_th232 <- 4.9475E-11

#time assumptions
age_of_earth_t0 <- 4.57E9
age_of_earth_t1 <- 3.7E9

#Isotopic Assumptions - Stage 1
s1_206PB.204PB <- 9.307
s1_207PB.204PB <- 10.294
s1_208PB.204PB <- 29.476

#Isotopic Assumptions - Stage 2 (Stacey & Kramer 1975)
s2_206PB.204PB <- 11.152
s2_207PB.204PB <- 12.998
s2_208PB.204PB <- 31.230

#Isotopic Proportion Assumptions - Stage 1 (Stacey & Kramer 1975)
s1_u <- 7.19
s1_w <- 32.21
s1_k <- 4.479833102

#Isotopic Proportion Assumptions - Stage 2 (Stacey & Kramer 1975)
s2_u <- 9.74
s2_w <- 37.19
s2_k <- 3.818275154

#µ or 238U/204Pb Estimates
uranium_lead_ratio_estimates <- matrix(6:12, nrow=7, ncol=1)



#slope
slopes <-(values_207.204-s2_207PB.204PB)/(values_206.204-s2_206PB.204PB)*137.88

model_age <- data.frame(A=ingots$X206Pb.204Pb, B=ingots$X207Pb.204Pb, C=ingots$X208Pb.204Pb, Slopes=slopes, ModelAge = 1:length(ingots$X206Pb.204Pb))

#Calculated Ages
Ages_new <- 1:4 *10000000
last <- Ages_new[length(Ages_new)]
add_val <- 10000000
n_adds <- 70
Ages <- cumsum(c(last, rep(add_val, n_adds)))

#Function
ModelAgeFunction <- function(Ages){
  (exp(decay_constant_u235*age_of_earth_t1)-exp(decay_constant_u235*Ages))/(exp(decay_constant_u238*age_of_earth_t1)-exp(decay_constant_u238*Ages))
}


#Iteration
lower_bound <- 0
upper_bound <- 700000000
num_intervals <- 70
interval_width <- (upper_bound - lower_bound) / num_intervals

#Vector of Slopes
slopes <- model_age$Slopes

#Integration
for (i in 1:length(slopes))  
{
  for (j in 1:length(num_intervals))
  {
    left_bound <- lower_bound + interval_width*(i-1)
    if (slopes[i] < ModelAgeFunction(left_bound + interval_width / 2)) 
    {
      model_age$ModelAge[j] <- (left_bound + interval_width / 2)
      break
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please state clearly what is your problem. Where is your code failing? what error is it throwing? As your questions stands, I can't identify how and if I can help you.

Comment: Does the data at the beginning correspond to the `ingot` object referenced later? Also, `values_207.204` and `values_206.204` are never defined. I also agree with @PavoDive that it would help if you described your goal and your specific question more explicitly.